# Trying to find the Git Branch a repo is on and pass it into a requirements.txt

Tags: python, requirements.txt

I am currently splitting out our large BDD project and moving the test code into the various applications so the BDD tests and the Application code are all in the same location.

As part of this I have created a library for shared code and pointed the requirements.txt file to this using

-e git+git@gitlab.xx.xxx:xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxBDD.git@"branchID(e.g develop)#egg=BehaveModules

Currently I am reliant on manually entering the Branch ID, so if changes are being made to the common library in line with the branch of code being developed I need to remember to update the branch ID.

Is there a way of doing this problematically and then pass this into my requirements.txt

for instance

```
Application_branch = get current git branch
if Application_branch present in BDD_Library Repo:
    branch = Application_branch
else: 
    branch = Develop

return branch

-e git+git@gitlab.xx.xxx:xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxBDD.git@branch#egg=BehaveModules
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of specifying variables in `requirements.txt`, You could create an `install.py` script and call `pip` by script.

```
import subprocess
import sys

_all_ = [
    "git+https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb.git@{}#egg=google_cloud_ndb",
    "requests"
]

latest_branch = 'master'


def install(packages):
    for package in packages:
        if 'git+' in package:
            subprocess.call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package.format(latest_branch)])
        else:
            subprocess.call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    install(_all_)
```

Instead of `subprocess` you can also use `pip` if you want:

```
import pip
def install(packages):
    for package in packages:
        pip.main(['install', package])
```